# Moblog - Can't get the template to work

Tags: templates, fields

I'm really confused about this moblog feature. And I can't understand what the documentation tells me, I don't feel it distinguish how the moblog template should look like, and what the email template should look like. So basically, I'd like some info on how the Moblog Template in the Control Panel should look like, and how the email itself should look like, to correspond with the right fields.

I have these fields that I'd like to populate with the data from the email.

```
{moblog_image}, {moblog_photographer}, {moblog_latlng}, {moblog_facts}
```

My Moblog Template looks like this:

```
{field name="moblog_image" format="none"}
   {images}
      <img src="{file}" width="{width}" height="{height}" alt="pic" />
   {/images}
{/field}

{field name="moblog_photographer}" format="none"}{text}{/field}    
{field name="moblog_latlng" format="none"}{text}{/field}
{field name="moblog_facts" format="none"}{text}{/field}
```

I'm really not sure if this is correct..
And below is how the email looks like:

```
{field:moblog_image}
image.png (image I paste in the email)
{/field:moblog_image}

{field:moblog_photographer}
John Appleseed
{/field:moblog_photographer}

{field:moblog_latlng}
3464,5896
{/field:moblog_latlng}

{field:moblog_facts}
Some facts
{/field:moblog_sekundaer}
```

Is this correct? What am I missing, because when I send this email and check the moblog, the entry contains basically the whole email, fields and all.

Answer (score 1):

The Moblog module simply creates entries from emails. It is admittedly a bit finicky though.

Can you verify that the entries are being created in your channel from the emails that you have sent?

If so, then you simply output the entries using the `{exp:channel:entries}` tag pair, just like you would for any other channel entry.

Comment: Yes, the entries are being created from the email I'm sending. In this moblog I have set that a default field. And this field picks up everything in my email, including all the tags that I want to populate elsewhere. So it's like moblog isn't interpreting the tags in the email and thus, puts everything in the default field. It doesn't put that data in the other fields as I want it to.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand now. Hmm.. I've never used a moblog with the fields in it, so I'm not sure what could be wrong.